# Minimal http service test without resetting up routes?

Tags: http, go, testing

Say I have a very simple Web service.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sanityTest)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

If I want to test it, I could minimally just have:

```
func ExampleTest() {
        server := httptest.NewServer(http.DefaultServeMux)
        defer server.Close()

        resp, err := http.Get(server.URL)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
        fmt.Println(string(body))

        // Output:
        // 200
        // text/plain; charset=utf-8
        // OK

}
```

But that will result in a 404, since it doesn't know about the routes. So what I've seen main_test.go code do, is re-setup the handles in the test file's init, like so:

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sanityTest)
}
```

Which leads to duplication, and inevitably I have to create a function in main.go like:

```
func setupRoutes() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", sanityTest)
}
```

Which I find a little ugly. Am I missing a trick to instantiate the routes from main.go and avoid the init?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to test `sanityTest` directly with `httptest.ResponseRecorder`?

Comment: Create a function that creates a mux, configures handlers in that mux and returns the mux as an http.Handler.  in main:  `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", setupMux())`  In tests:  `server := httptest.NewServer(setupMux())`.  Because it's difficult to audit additions to http.DefaultServeMux, it's usually best to avoid http.DefaultServeMux in any serious application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-use routes between tests and main.go file, also it's helpful if you want to mock something in your handlers (add a new argument to `router()` func below)

main.go:

```
func sanityTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "sanity test")
}

func router() *http.ServeMux {
    h := http.NewServeMux()
    h.HandleFunc("/", sanityTest)
    return h
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router())
}
```

main_test.go:

```
func TestSanity(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        uri  string
        want string
    }{
        {"1", "/", "sanity test"},
    }

    ts := httptest.NewServer(router())
    defer ts.Close()

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            url := ts.URL + tt.uri
            resp, _ := http.Get(url)
            respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            resp.Body.Close()

            got := string(respBody)
            if got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("got %s, Want %s", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep up the videos. I updated https://travis-ci.org/kaihendry/count/builds/532820235?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification with your advice.